# Bootstrap Carousel slider on hover image border automatically disappears

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm scaling image on hover but when image hover border disappears automatically. I'm using `li` width in percentage because of responsive if i define `li` width in `pixel` some media screen and even one pixel difference in screen `li` mess up so that is why i'm using width in percentage.

```
<div class="carousel slide main-slider"> 
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <ul class="carousel-inner list-unstyled no-mb">
                            <li class="item active hero"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                            <li class="item active"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                            <li class="item active"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                            <li class="item active"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                            <li class="item active"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="carousel-inner list-unstyled no-mb hidden">
                            <li class="item active hero"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                            <li class="item active"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                            <li class="item active"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                            <li class="item active"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                            <li class="item active"> <a href="javascript:;">
                                <div class="thumb-container">
                                    <div class="thumb-img img-fit"> <img src="inc-media/thumb.jpg"> </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-caption"> <span class="label label-slider">First Look</span>
                                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-row row no-mb timing">
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 DEC 2016</li>
                                        <li class="ps-col col-xs-6"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 12</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </a> </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Controls --> 
                        <a class="left carousel-control"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-slider ul li.item {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 29%;
    height: 162.5px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-slider ul li.item:hover{
    padding-right:1px;}
.main-slider ul li.item:hover img {
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.260, 0.695, 0.375, 0.965);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.0260, 0.695, 0.375, 0.965);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.02);
    transform: scale(1.02);
}
.main-slider .thumb-container {
    padding-bottom: 163px;
}
.main-slider li.item.hero .thumb-container {
    padding-bottom: 325px;
}
.main-slider ul li.item {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.main-slider ul li.item:nth-last-child(3), .main-slider ul li.item:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
}
.main-slider ul li.item:nth-last-child(2), .main-slider ul li.item:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
.main-slider .carousel-caption {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2px 10px 0px 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.72);
    text-align: start;
}
.main-slider ul li.item h3 {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.main-slider li.item.hero {
    width: 42%;
    height: 325px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
.main-slider li.item.hero h3 {
    font-size: 28px;
}
.main-slider .timing li {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-slider .timing li:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}
.label-slider {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.79);
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -23px;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
}
.main-slider li.item.hero .label-slider {
    font-size: 16px;
    top: -27px;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
/* slider controller setting
------------------------------*/
.main-slider .carousel-control {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
    width: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.main-slider:hover .carousel-control {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
.main-slider:hover .carousel-control:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: and ......... your question?

Comment: hehehe my question is on hover li right border automatically disappears.

Comment: `.main-slider .carousel-control {    z-index: 199};`